# Next() and prev() to hide and show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a simple next and prev to show and hide div. I'm using bootstrap 4.

I'm using .next() and .prev() to make a `slideshow` in my site.

But now i facing multiple problems. First when i click next it's skipping one div, then when i click prev the div is not showing.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


 $(".serviceparent .parentofparent").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });
    
    $("#nextservice").click(function(){

        if ($(".serviceparent .parentofparent").next().length != 0)
        {   
            $(".serviceparent .parentofparent").next().show().prev().hide();
        }
        else {
            $(".serviceparent .parentofparent").hide();
            $(".serviceparent .parentofparent").show();
        }
                        return false;

    });

    $("#prevservice").click(function(){
        if ($(".serviceparent .parentofparent").prev().length != 0)
            $(".serviceparent .parentofparent").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
            $(".serviceparent .parentofparent").hide();
            $(".serviceparent .parentofparent").show();
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <div class="serviceparent row flex-row flex-nowrap text-center" style="white-space: nowrap">
               
                 
                 <br><br><br>

                    <div id="div1" class="parentofparent col-12 col-sm-6 col-md col-lg">
                       <div class="servicecontainer">
                            <i class="fa fa-globe fa-5x"></i>
                              <div class="servicetitle">
                                  <h2>Web Apps</h2>
                              </div>
                             
                       </div>
                    </div>

                     <div id="div2" class="parentofparent col-12 col-sm-6 col-md col-lg">
                       <div class="servicecontainer">
                            <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-5x"></i>
                              <div class="servicetitle">
                                  <h2>Desktop Apps</h2>
                              </div>
                              
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div id="div3" class="parentofparent col-12 col-sm-6 col-md col-lg">
                       <div class="servicecontainer">
                            <i class="fa fa-signal fa-5x"></i>
                              <div class="servicetitle">
                                  <h2>Networking</h2>
                              </div>
                                                   </div>
                    </div>
                
                </div>   <ul class="list-inline mx-auto justify-content-center servicenavparent">
                      <li id="prevservice" class="list-inline-item servicenav fa fa-arrow-left">PREV</li> 
                      <li id="nextservice" class="list-inline-item servicenav fa fa-arrow-right">NEXT</li>
                 </ul>
```

so, how to fix this, what did i miss ? thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no concept of "current" - ie what are you trying to move to next *from*. By using `.serviceparent .parentofparent` you're selecting all of the .parentofparent items, and the show/hide acts on all of them, so the final one shown will be the last one (it's only "skipping 1" because there's only 3 - if there were 4 it would skip 2...)

Without changing too much of the code, you can change the selectors to `$(".serviceparent .parentofparent:visible")` (except the first which hides the others) to indicate that you want the next one after the current one that's visible.

An extra check is needed for the last one, to show the first one. In this case you can hide all and show first/last:

```
$(".serviceparent .parentofparent:first").show();
```

one issue with using `.next()` / `.prev()` is that you're not checking if it's giving the correct item.  In your html, `$(".parentofparent:first").prev()` will give a `<br/>` - so you can add a filter to your .next/.prev to give only the types you want, eg:

```
if ($(".serviceparent .parentofparent:visible").prev(".parentofparent").length != 0)
```

Updated snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $(".serviceparent .parentofparent").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
      $(this).hide();
  });

  $("#nextservice").click(function() {

    if ($(".serviceparent .parentofparent:visible").next(".parentofparent").length != 0) {
      $(".serviceparent .parentofparent:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    } else {
      $(".serviceparent .parentofparent").hide();
      $(".serviceparent .parentofparent:first").show();
    }
    return false;

  });

  $("#prevservice").click(function() {
    if ($(".serviceparent .parentofparent:visible").prev(".parentofparent").length != 0)
      $(".serviceparent .parentofparent:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
    else {
      $(".serviceparent .parentofparent").hide();
      $(".serviceparent .parentofparent:last").show();
    }
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="serviceparent row flex-row flex-nowrap text-center" style="white-space: nowrap">

  <br><br><br>

  <div id="div1" class="parentofparent col-12 col-sm-6 col-md col-lg">
    <div class="servicecontainer">
      <i class="fa fa-globe fa-5x"></i>
      <div class="servicetitle">
        <h2>Web Apps</h2>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="div2" class="parentofparent col-12 col-sm-6 col-md col-lg">
    <div class="servicecontainer">
      <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-5x"></i>
      <div class="servicetitle">
        <h2>Desktop Apps</h2>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="div3" class="parentofparent col-12 col-sm-6 col-md col-lg">
    <div class="servicecontainer">
      <i class="fa fa-signal fa-5x"></i>
      <div class="servicetitle">
        <h2>Networking</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<ul class="list-inline mx-auto justify-content-center servicenavparent">
  <li id="prevservice" class="list-inline-item servicenav fa fa-arrow-left">PREV</li>
  <li id="nextservice" class="list-inline-item servicenav fa fa-arrow-right">NEXT</li>
</ul>
```

---

An alternative would be to add/remove classes and use that, eg:

```
$(".active").removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
```

and hide via css

```
.serviceparent .parentofparent { display:none; }
.active { display:block; }
```